# Rails 5 Active Model Serializer display has many conditions in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, has-many, active-model-serializers

In my project I have those models and relationships:

```js
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :segments, inverse_of: :course, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :segments, :allow_destroy => true

end

class Segment < ApplicationRecord
  validates :data ,presence: true, if: :segment_is_video?
  validates :segment_type ,presence: true
  validates_presence_of :course

  belongs_to :course, inverse_of: :segments
  has_many :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :allow_destroy => true

   def segment_is_video?
     segment_type == 'Video'
   end

end

class Question < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :segment
  belongs_to :segment, inverse_of: :questions

end
```

I want to display the data field only if the type is Video, and I want to display questions array only if type field is Quiz. I'm using Active Model Serializer for that but it's not working. the data still displaying when the type is Quiz and the question array doesn't show at all.
this is my code for the serializers:

```js
class CourseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :author
  has_many :segments

  def root
    'Course'
  end

end

class SegmentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :unit_id, :unit_title, :name, :segment_type, :data
  belongs_to :course

  has_many :questions, if: -> { isQuiz }

  def root
    'Segments'
  end

  def include_data?
    object.segment_type == 'Video'
  end

  def isQuiz
    object.segment_type == 'Quiz'
  end
end

class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :question, :answer1, :answer2, :answer3, :answer4, :correct
  belongs_to :segment

  def root
    'Question'
  end
end
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that `include_data?` is called anywhere. I also don't see a `Video` or `Quiz` model in the code you posted

Comment: I don't have Quiz and Video model. I have segment model which contains segment type. if the type is video - in the gui (active admin) the data filed is a must and need to contain data. if t's quiz them validates on the question and answers. I just want to show and hide data depends on what value in type